# How to use MediaSessionCompat and keep backward compatibility with RemoteControlClient?

Tags: android

I want to replace my android RemoteControlClient class in my application with a new one using MediaSession, but that not working with API level < 21, MediaSessionCompat seem to work without crashing old devices, but no more ARTWORK or song infos on the LockScreen is displayed...

Any snippet or infos for me ?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of revision 22 of the Support-v4 library, the [source code for MediaSessionCompat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/media-compat/java/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.java) shows that it now will automatically register and use a `RemoteControlClient` in API 14-20 devices before switching to `MediaSession` on API21+ devices.

Comment: This seems really counterintuitive. What is the reason for using MediaSessionCompat at all?

Comment: Instead of guarding each and every call with a `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` if statement, you can use `MediaSessionCompat` directly. The alternatives of not supporting MediaSession at all (leading to a suboptimal experience for what will be a growing percentage of users) or writing error-prone code (missing just a single if statement would cause your app to crash) aren't sustainable coding practices.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes there is the Compat, but how can you tell the MediaSession to show the Lockscreen controls? For lollipop you add the session to a notification which is not available prior to API 21.

Comment: @Asfaloth - you use the (now deprecated) [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) class to support v14-v20 devices.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Okay thanks. Thought there might be another way to just use MediaSession.

Comment: But Google play music seems doing something similar I'm android wear, how that works?

Comment: @anisite, are you using the MediaSessionCompat to receive media button intents ? If yes, it is working fine on Lollipop ? Could you post a code snippet of how do you instantiate and use the MediaSession ? I am trying here to use, but even returning true when i call isActive, i'm not receiving any intents for media button.

Comment: Since the support library r22 just came out,  you need to update your answer, Ian

Comment: Thanks @Wayne - I've updated my post to take into account the changes in revision 22 (which adds `RemoteControlClient` support for API14-20 devices).

Comment: The MediaSessionCompat doesn't show lockscreen controls on KitKat while it does on Lollipop. Any help?

Comment: @Aky - that's interesting as there are no such thing as lockscreen controls on Lollipop (unless you are using something separate from `MediaSessionCompat` such as [NotificationCompat.MediaStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html). Make sure you are passing a valid [Media Button receiver](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls) when constructing the `MediaSessionCompat` object.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I used everything but it doesn't show up on KitKat. And by Lollipop I meant the notification shows

Comment: @ianhanniballake
I need your help