# Do MediaSession and MediaSessionManager have backward compatibility?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I read a good post [here](http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165) on how to use notification buttons to interact with a mediaplayer service to play, pause, skip etc.

The [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager.html) says this was introduced in API level 21, does anyone know the alternatives for this for lower API level? How does this work on lower API level devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best answer I've found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26474423/785716

It seems that the two methods aren't really backwards compatible at all.

Answer (score 4):

An updated version of [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) was recently released that uses RemoteControlClient for APIs levels 14-20. Unfortunately, there is no Compat version of MediaSessionManager at this time.